# Solve first order non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the following differential equation :

$$x'(t) = \frac{1+x^2(t)}{\sqrt[3]{t} \, [x(t)+1]^{2} + 3tx(t)}$$

I think it has to be simplified, do you see some substitutions ? Or any idea to start the calculus?

Comment: What does $x^2(t)$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WIP stands for 'Work In Progress' there may still be room for another answer. The original equation reads
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt[3]{t}(x+1)^2+3tx}$$
Take reciprocals and rearrange to Bernoulli's differential equation.
$$\frac{dt}{dx}-\frac{3x}{1+x^2}\cdot t=\frac{(x+1)^2}{1+x^2}\cdot t^{\frac13}$$
We solve by letting $t=u^n$. Then we need $n-1=\frac13n$, so $n=\frac32$, $t=u^{\frac32}$ and now
$$\frac32u^{\frac12}\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{3x}{1+x^2}\cdot u^{\frac32}=\frac{(1+x)^2}{1+x^2}\cdot u^{\frac12}$$
Now we have transformed to a first order linear differential equation,
$$\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\cdot u=\frac{(1+x)^2}{1+x^2}$$
The integrating factor is
$$\mu=e^{\int\frac{-2x}{1+x^2}dx}=e^{-\ln(1+x^2)}=\frac1{1+x^2}$$
Multiplying by $\mu$, we arrive at
$$\begin{align}\frac d{dx}\left(\frac u{1+x^2}\right) & =\frac1{1+x^2}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}\cdot u=\frac{(1+x)^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\\
 & = \frac{1+2x+x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}=\frac1{1+x^2}+\frac{2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\end{align}$$
So now we can integrate to get
$$\frac u{1+x^2}=\frac{t^{\frac23}}{1+x^2}=\tan^{-1}x-\frac1{1+x^2}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
x'(t)&=&\dfrac{1+x^2(t)}{\sqrt[3]t(x(t)+1)^2+3tx(t)}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}&=&\dfrac{1+x^2}{\sqrt[3]t(x+1)^2+3tx}&\text{convert to Leibniz notation}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}&=&\dfrac{\sqrt[3]t(x+1)^2+3tx}{1+x^2}&\text{taking reciprocal of both sides}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}&=&\dfrac{\sqrt[3]t(x^2+2x+1)+3tx}{1+x^2}&\text{expand}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}&=&\dfrac{\sqrt[3]tx^2+2\sqrt[3]tx+\sqrt[3]t+3tx}{1+x^2}&\text{distribute}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}&=&\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]tx^2+\sqrt[3]t)+2\sqrt[3]tx+3tx}{1+x^2}&\text{regroup}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}&=&\sqrt[3]t+(2\sqrt[3]t+3t)\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}&\text{}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\tan\theta}&=&\sqrt[3]t+(2\sqrt[3]t+3t)\dfrac{\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta}&\text{substitute }x=\tan\theta\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\theta}\dfrac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm d\tan\theta}&=&\sqrt[3]t+(2\sqrt[3]t+3t)\dfrac{\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta}&\text{chain rule}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\theta}\dfrac{1}{\sec^2\theta}&=&\sqrt[3]t+(2\sqrt[3]t+3t)\dfrac{\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta}&\text{}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\theta}&=&\sqrt[3]t\sec^2\theta+(2\sqrt[3]t+3t)\tan\theta&\text{}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\theta}&=&\sqrt[3]t(\tan^2\theta+1)+(2\sqrt[3]t+3t)\tan\theta&\text{}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\theta}&=&\sqrt[3]t\tan^2\theta+(2\sqrt[3]t+3t)\tan\theta+\sqrt[3]t&\text{}\\
\end{array}$$

WIP